# Escape/continue running program if error (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, escaping, alchemy, cloudsight

I want to try and run my code, even if I encounter an error. I'll state where I believe I get the error below and what the error is:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'simple_oauth'
require 'cloudsight'
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'
require 'open-uri'
require 'openssl'
require 'hpricot'


#ALCHEMY

 file='C:\\Users\\ENTER USERNAME\\Desktop\\cloudsight.txt'
 f = File.open(file, "r")
 f.each_line {|line|

 tstart = 'name"=>"'
 tstop = '"'
 term = line[/#{tstart}(.*?)#{tstop}/m, 1]

 url = 'http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls'
 service = '/text/TextGetRankedTaxonomy'
 apikey = '?apikey=ENTER ALCHEMY API KEY'
 thething = '&text='
 termencoded = URI::encode(term)
 fullurl = url + service + apikey + thething + termencoded

 sleep 1
 opener = open(fullurl, 'Accept-Encoding' => '') {|f| f.read } 
 #print opener
```

I think I get the error at this point.

```
 lstart = '<label>/'
 lstop = '</label>'
 label = opener[/#{lstart}(.*?)#{lstop}/m, 1]

 sleep 1
 cstart = '<score>'
 cstop = '</score>'
 confidence = opener[/#{cstart}(.*?)#{cstop}/m, 1]

 #data = label + ',' + confidence + ',' + line
 print label
 print confidence
 print "\n"

 }
```

This is the error I seem to get:

```
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:304:in `escape': undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Any ideas as to how I can pass the error/escape it/ or make a string come up instead?

Comment: Will this work? label = opener[/#{lstart}(.*?)#{lstop}/m, 1] rescue '' and this    confidence = opener[/#{cstart}(.*?)#{cstop}/m, 1] rescue ''

Comment: Where are you using gsub? The code you posted doesn't include it.

Comment: then I get the following:

 C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/tes453:45: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/tes453:51: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
Do you know how I can get around this?

Comment: I don't think I'm using gsub

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the error is coming from this line:

```
termencoded = URI::encode(term)
```

And is probably happening because `term` is nil.  Add some debugging to see what `term` is set to before that line is called. If you're okay with `term` being blank you could change that line to this:

```
termencoded = URI::encode(term.to_s)
```

Whether or not that's acceptable for your program I can't say.

I wouldn't try to suppress the error though. Something isn't working right and you should figure out what it is and how to handle it.

Comment: term seems to already be a string. I added your code anyway and I seem to get the same results. What I'm doing is retrieving data using the alchemy api. Sometimes the the data is there, in which case I receive it. If it's not there, this error throws up.

Comment: Interesting. Does the stacktrace not point you to the line in your code that the error originates on?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Turns out it's an issue on alchemys side in this instance. The taxonomy search just wasn't able to find a term